# Save user input

Tags: c#, save, openfiledialog

So basically,
I have a OpenFileDialog fully working which displays the chosen dir in a textbox.
But I'm wondering how would I save the users input so when they would restart the application it would stay in the textbox? so they wouldn't have to do it over every time.
I understand this might be a stupid question, but I've been googeling some time and found nothing like this. Thanks.

Comment: You're more expieranced. You know what to look for! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(File.Exists(@"path.txt"))
            textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"path.txt");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(File.Exists(@"path.txt") == false)
            File.Create(@"path.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(@"path.txt", textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Just write it in a file, don't forget to include System.IO in your references.

Comment: I did this but I'm not too sure how to test if it actually works. How would I fully test it?

Comment: Running your application? I mean, create a button where you write the file when click on it, in the Form1() method fill the textbox reading what is in the file. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Yeah I got that now, thanks. But how would I test if that code works? Cause if I just debug it, would it just reset every time?

Comment: If I got it right:
saveFileDialog1.FileName = File.ReadAllText(@"path.txt");